# Color Barplot by Count

Tags: r, graphics, plot

I am creating a barplot in R and want to color each bar by bar height (count)

Currently what I have:

```
z=rnorm(n,1)
Z=runif(n)
h=barplot(Z)
```

I have pictures but not enough reputation to post them. 
So here is the example in MatLab:
[MatLab-Color bars by height](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f10-19972.html#f10-23913)

Comment: Error: could not find function "rand"

Comment: sorry rand is the matlab code. I think I used rnorm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
library(ggplot2)
d = data.frame(x = rnorm(100))
ggplot(d) + geom_bar(aes(x, fill = ..count..))
```

Answer (score 7):

In addition to baptiste's ggplot2 solution, here's a simple example using `barplot`:

```
Z <- sample(20,15,replace = TRUE)
barplot(Z,col = heat.colors(max(Z))[Z])
```

which produces something like this:

[image]